# Open new window with all the controls in it disabled/UnClickable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to open a new window through javascript on a button click with an url read from back end. However based on some permission, I should stop the user from modifying any content in the newly opened window.

I have checked out few properties in window object specs properties and it doesn't seem to be fitting to address this scenario.

```js
if(!hasPermission)
{
// Open the new window with readonly content.
var newWindow = window.open(inputUrl);
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try the codes,

```
$("#id").attr ("disabled","disabled")
```

Or you can try with property of html elements as follows

```
$("#id").prop("disabled",true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use [session storage to achive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) this?

You could add a flag in the session storage, and during the page load, you verify if the page load was made in other tab. After the verification, you remove the flag from the `sessionStorage`, allowing to distingue from a normal page load or a page loaded made after open a new tab in the browser.

Here some example:

```
openTab(inputUrl) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('tabWasOpen', true);
    window.open(inputUrl)
}

verifyPremissions() {
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('tabWasOpen')) {
        //means the page was loaded
    }
    sessionStorage.getItem('tabWasOpen', false)
}

document.onload = () => {
  verifyPremissions();
}
```

**Possible problems with this approach**

If the new tab open does not load, until the user closes the browser, the value on sessionStorage will still be set to true, which could lead to erratic behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
const disableControls = w => {
    // by cloning and replacing the elements we
    // remove all event listener added by javascript
    const body = w.document.body.cloneNode(true);
    w.document.body.parentNode.replaceChild(body, w.document.body);
    // disable form submits and links
    for(let node of w.document.body.children) {
        node.addEventListener('click', e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        });
    }
};

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
    let newWindow = window.open('test.html');
    newWindow.addEventListener('load', e => disableControls(newWindow), false);
});
```

example for `test.html` (used as source for the popup)

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">abc</a>
<form>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<button>lulu</button>

<script>
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => alert('alriiight'));
</script>
```

I'll hope this helps